# Teamcity document file size limit

Tags: teamcity

I have this issue where, when running teamcity build up till the publishing artifact phase it runs unlimited loop as shown below

[Step 3/3] Publishing artifacts

```
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
     [Publication artifacts] Sending ....Web.3196.01.nupkg
```

I have discovered that it is due to the multiple document files which is about a total of 50 MB.

The question is does anyone know what is the document file size limit that teamcity support?

and another question is, is there a way to increase the file size limit?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you are facing this known issue: [Failure to publish artifacts to server behind IIS reverse proxy](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Known+Issues#KnownIssues-FailuretopublishartifactstoserverbehindIISreverseproxy)
In short, IIS reverse proxy has low default file upload limit (less then 30Mb per file) and must be configured.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have found the source of the problem. Yup. is the IIS configuration file size limit